# Inheritance with JAXB (unmarshalling)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have many entities with common properties. There is no xml schema, so I write jaxb entities on my own.

```
abstract class SuperEntity {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;

    @XmlElement
    public void setId() { .. sets Id .. }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName() { .. sets name .. }
}

// id and name are null after deserialization .. they are completely ignored
// there are other entities such as this, I don't want to repeat my code
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({SuperEntity.class})
class SpecificEntity extends SuperEntity {
    protected String specificField;

    @XmlElement
    public void setSpecificField() { .. sets specific field .. }
}
```

SuperEntity is not deserialized (unmarshelled) at all, leaving fields null. If i copy fields and setters from superclass to specific class, it works, but I dont want to just copy that code to every child entity. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class definitions to

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({SpecificEntity.class})
abstract class SuperEntity {


@XmlRootElement
class SpecificEntity extends SuperEntity {
```

Comment: Throws InstantiationException, because SuperEntity is abstract. If I wont make it abstract, throws IllegalArgumentException, beacause it cannot set specificField to SuperEntity.

Comment: @Filip - Marshal out your object model to see what you should pass in on the unmarshal.  You are getting that exception because you are not including an `xsi:type` in your XML.  See:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html

Answer (score 0):

When JAXB is processing a class model it will also process super classes (the ones not annotated with `@XmlTransient`).  By default it won't process subclasses.  The `@XmlSeeAlso` needs to go on the super class and reference the subclasses.

Comment: Should I initialize jaxbContext with Superclass or Childclass that I'm trying to deserialize?

Comment: @Filip - You can create it on the subclasses, or the super class if it contains an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation that references the subclasses.